# Importing a C# DLL into C++ for use with JNI

Tags: c#, c++, dll, java-native-interface, include

I am writing a program in Java which must use a DLL file (which is one written in C#), I figured the best way to do this is to write a C++ program as an interface, and then use JNI. The C++ program will be responsible for using the DLL in a JNI friendly way so that I can then call it from my Java program.

I'm trying to include a DLL file in C++ but I am getting the following error on compilation.

```
warning C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
```

The way I am including said DLL:

```
#include "LibraryName.dll"
```

I am including/using or making any incorrect assumptions about the use of DLLs in this way? How would I fix this error?

Comment: You can't call a .net library from C++ unless it's managed C++ (which is not the case)

Comment: You don't include dll files. You have to keep them in the same directory as the executable. I suggest doing some googling about the JNI and dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid C++ and make calls from Java to C# and back directly, but you'll have to bootstrap the whole thing from C# side:

1. In your Java program create a class and expose a JNI method:

```java
public class Foo {
    static native void bar(); // This method will be implemented in C#
}
```

2. Compile the Java program into a JAR file
3. Write a "bootstrap" program in C# that loads the DLL, starts the JVM in-process with the JAR in classpath, and uses JNI `RegisterNatives` to provide the callback for `bar()` method and invoke your DLL accordingly.

Please see Apache Ignite.NET code as an example of cross-platform .NET/Java interop:

- Java-side methods: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/platform/callback/PlatformCallbackUtils.java
- C#-side implementations are provided in `RegisterNatives`: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core/Impl/Unmanaged/Jni/Callbacks.cs#L120
- C# can also call into any Java class/method: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/607cdb0dafe8cb8c6595ab776b66a1a25cba018d/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core/Impl/Unmanaged/Jni/Env.cs#L126

Feel free to copy and modify this code to your needs, Apache license allows that.

The whole thing is rather complicated, but it is the most performant approach. The only alternative is to run .NET and Java in separate processes and use pipes or some other mechanism to communicate.

Comment: Absolutely great answer, thanks for reading the question and suggesting something better than what I was hoping for!

Comment: I have managed to use modified Apache ignite code to launch JVM with my JAR and register a native method, please could you explain how would I now go about running the JAR file (invoking the Main method)? As of now i have `Jvm.GetOrCreate(options).AttachCurrentThread()` which returns an Env object.

Comment: @ChristianBenner use JNI `FindClass` to retrieve your class, then `GetStaticMethodId`, then `CallStaticVoidMethod`. Let me know if I should prepare a working example.

Comment: Got it working! Thank you so much for your time and help, I am now successfully running C# code from my Java application :)

Comment: Awesome! I know it is not easy to get right, glad to hear it worked :)